Get the size (height, width and S=height*width in em) of the displayed image and draw it
How to get the size (height, width and S=height*width in em) of the displayed image and draw it?
Like here:

MWE:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{pgfmath}
\newcommand\pttoem[1]{%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\len{#1/1em}\len{}em
}
\newlength\myHeight
\newlength\myWidth
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \adjustbox{gstore width=\myWidth, gstore height=\myHeight, center}{%
            \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image}%
            }
    \end{figure}
    
Height: \the\myHeight \qquad \textbf{\pttoem{\the\myHeight}}

Width: \the\myWidth \qquad \textbf{\pttoem{\the\myWidth}}
\end{document}


you have added a space on left and right, \fbox{a} is not the same as \fbox{ a }  and you have the second form

Thank you, @David Carlisle.

The following uses TikZ do draw your measurements and a temporary box for the measurements (instead of adjustbox).
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\pttoem[1]{\fpeval{round((#1)/1em, 2)}em}
\newcommand\pttoemsq[2]{\fpeval{round((#1)/1em*(#2)/1em, 2)}}

\newsavebox\measuredgraphicBox
\NewDocumentCommand \includemeasuredgraphics { O{} m }
  {%
    \begingroup
      \sbox\measuredgraphicBox{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt](img){\usebox\measuredgraphicBox};%
        \draw[red,<->]
          (img.north east) ++(0,5pt)coordinate(img1)
          (img.north west) ++(0,5pt)coordinate(img2)
          (img1) -- node[above]{\pttoem{\the\wd\measuredgraphicBox}} (img2)
          ;
        \draw[red,<->]
          (img.north east) ++(5pt,0)coordinate(img1)
          (img.south east) ++(5pt,0)coordinate(img2)
          (img1) -- node[right]{\pttoem{\the\ht\measuredgraphicBox}} (img2)
          ;
        \node[red,fill=white] at (img)
          {\pttoemsq{\the\ht\measuredgraphicBox}{\the\wd\measuredgraphicBox}}
          ;
      \end{tikzpicture}%
    \endgroup
  }

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \includemeasuredgraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
\end{figure}
\end{document}

(image outdated, new precision is rounded to 2 decimal places)


Thank you, @Skillmon. One question. Why is the drawing not centered? \begin{center}
\begin{figure}
\includemeasuredgraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
\end{figure}
\end{center}

@Youra_P because you use center outside of figure and not vice versa. However, you shouldn't use the center-environment inside floats (such as figure) as that yields undesirable spacing, instead use \centering like so: \begin{figure}\centering<your contents>\end{figure}.

@Youra_P please note that I had a superfluous space after \end{tikzpicture} which is now corrected.

Error in area calculation: 9.95766 * 6.16245 = 61.3635819! The calculated value does not match. what's the problem, @Skillmon ?

@Youra_P most likely float precision and pgfmath. I could change the calculation to l3fp if you want, that should yield better results (but still is affected by float precision, which it just cranks up to 10 decimal places).

Can make 2 decimal places?

@Youra_P I made the change to the more precise l3fp and added round to limit the output to two places.

A solution that relies on expl3 commands (including the experimental l3draw package) only and makes heavy use of the concept of coffins:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{l3draw}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\dim_new:N \g_annotated_graphic_width_dim
\dim_new:N \g_annotated_graphic_height_dim
\coffin_new:N \l_annotated_graphic_image_coffin
\coffin_new:N \l_annotated_graphic_area_label_coffin
\coffin_new:N \l_annotated_graphic_width_label_coffin
\coffin_new:N \l_annotated_graphic_height_label_coffin

\dim_new:N \l_annotated_graphic_temp_dim
\coffin_new:N \l_annotated_graphic_temp_coffin

\cs_new:Npn \l_annotated_graphic_arrows_label:n #1 {
    \draw_begin:
        \hcoffin_set:Nn \l_annotated_graphic_temp_coffin {
            \l_annotated_graphic_format_em:n {#1}
        }
        \draw_coffin_use:Nnn \l_annotated_graphic_temp_coffin { hc } { vc }
        \dim_set:Nn \l_annotated_graphic_temp_dim {
            \coffin_wd:N \l_annotated_graphic_temp_coffin
        }
        \draw_path_moveto:n { 0.5 * \l_annotated_graphic_temp_dim + 5pt , 0pt }
        \draw_path_lineto:n { 0.5 * #1 , 0pt }
        \draw_path_moveto:n { 0.5 * #1 - 5pt , 5pt }
        \draw_path_lineto:n { 0.5 * #1 , 0pt }
        \draw_path_lineto:n { 0.5 * #1 - 5pt , - 5pt }
        \draw_path_use_clear:n { stroke }
        \draw_path_moveto:n { -0.5 * \l_annotated_graphic_temp_dim - 5pt , 0pt }
        \draw_path_lineto:n { -0.5 * #1 , 0pt }
        \draw_path_moveto:n { -0.5 * #1 + 5pt , 5pt }
        \draw_path_lineto:n { -0.5 * #1 , 0pt }
        \draw_path_lineto:n { -0.5 * #1 + 5pt , - 5pt }
        \draw_path_use_clear:n { stroke }
    \draw_end:
}

\cs_new:Npn \l_annotated_graphic_format_em:n #1 {
    \fp_to_decimal:n {  
        floor( #1 / 1em * 10000 ) / 10000
    } ~ em
}

\cs_new:Npn \l_annotated_graphic_format_em:nn #1#2 {
    \fp_to_decimal:n {  
        floor( #1 / 1em * 10000 ) / 10000 * 
        floor( #2 / 1em * 10000 ) / 10000
    } ~ em
}

\NewDocumentCommand { \AnnotatedGraphic } { m O{} m } {
    \vcoffin_set:Nnn \l_annotated_graphic_image_coffin {#1} { 
        \includegraphics[width = #1, #2]{#3}
    }
    \dim_set:Nn \g_annotated_graphic_width_dim 
        { \coffin_wd:N \l_annotated_graphic_image_coffin }
    \dim_set:Nn \g_annotated_graphic_height_dim 
        { \coffin_ht:N \l_annotated_graphic_image_coffin + 
          \coffin_dp:N \l_annotated_graphic_image_coffin }
    \vcoffin_set:Nnn \l_annotated_graphic_width_label_coffin {
        \g_annotated_graphic_width_dim 
    } { 
        \l_annotated_graphic_arrows_label:n { 
            \g_annotated_graphic_width_dim
        } 
    }
    \vcoffin_set:Nnn \l_annotated_graphic_height_label_coffin { 
        \g_annotated_graphic_height_dim 
    } {
        \l_annotated_graphic_arrows_label:n {  
            \g_annotated_graphic_height_dim
        }
    }
    \hcoffin_set:Nn \l_annotated_graphic_area_label_coffin { 
        \l_annotated_graphic_format_em:nn { 
            \g_annotated_graphic_width_dim 
        } {
            \g_annotated_graphic_height_dim
        } 
    }
    \coffin_attach:NnnNnnnn 
        \l_annotated_graphic_image_coffin { hc } { t }
        \l_annotated_graphic_width_label_coffin { hc } { b }
            { 0pt } { 10pt }
    \coffin_rotate:Nn \l_annotated_graphic_height_label_coffin { 90 }
    \coffin_attach:NnnNnnnn 
        \l_annotated_graphic_image_coffin { r } { vc }
        \l_annotated_graphic_height_label_coffin { hc } { t }
            { 10pt } { 0pt }
    \coffin_attach:NnnNnnnn 
        \l_annotated_graphic_image_coffin { hc } { vc }
        \l_annotated_graphic_area_label_coffin { hc } { vc }
            { 0pt } { 0pt }
    \coffin_typeset:Nnnnn \l_annotated_graphic_image_coffin { l } { b } 
        { 0pt } { 0pt }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}%
        \centering%
        \AnnotatedGraphic{5cm}{example-image-duck}%
    \end{figure}
\end{document}


